Generate a range of dates using SQL for every date in column in a table
I have a colmn in table containing the dates. I want to generate a table that contains a date range for every date in the column. For example, the table1 may look like this:
  id    mydate
  1     06/07/2024
  8     05/03/2024

I want a table from the above table as follows (2 days before and 2 days after for each date in mydate column:
  id   yourdate
   1    06/09/2024
   1    06/08/2024
   1    06/07/2024
   1    06/06/2024
   1    06/05/2024
   8    05/05/2024
   8    05/04/2024
   8    05/03/2024
   8    05/02/2024
   8    05/01/2024

There is a resolved simpler question here Generate a range of dates using SQL.

Yet another one:
select id, mydate + level - 3 as yourdate
from data 
connect by level <= 5 and prior id = id and prior sys_guid() is not null;


Wow, this is fascinating to me. This solution is better suited to my needs since my range is 'dynamic' and can extend to a month or more. The previous two solutions were less satisfactory. Thank you!

By the way, this code in intriguing to me, never saw 'prior' key word before.  Keep learning!

Oracle function should be this,
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.mydate + d.day_diff AS yourdate
FROM
    initial_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT -2 AS day_diff
    UNION ALL SELECT -1
    UNION ALL SELECT 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
) d
ON 1 = 1
ORDER BY
    t.id,
    yourdate;

There is MYSQL solution for this,
SELECT
    t.id,
    DATE_ADD(t.mydate, INTERVAL d.day_diff DAY) AS yourdate
FROM
    initial_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT -2 AS day_diff
    UNION ALL SELECT -1
    UNION ALL SELECT 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
) d
ON 1 = 1
ORDER BY
    t.id,
    yourdate;

here is the output.


DATE_ADD is not a valid Oracle function and the interval syntax is invalid. You want to use SELECT t.id, t.mydate + d.day_diff AS yourdate

Also, SELECT requires a FROM clause in Oracle unless you are using Oracle 23 or later.

Thank you, I added Oracle function, I missed that point in the question.
